# Determine whether the systems Ax = b and Dx = b are consistent or inconsistent. If consistent solve the system.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

$$\text{Let} \;
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 5 & 3\\
1 & 0 & 8\\
\end{bmatrix},\;
D = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 3\\
3 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},\;
\text{and b =}
\begin{bmatrix}
21\\
9\\
-1\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

Determine whether the systems $A$**x** = **b** and $D$**x** = **b** are consistent or inconsistent. If consistent, solve the system.

I setup an augmented matrix [$A$|**b**] and found

$$\text{x =}
\begin{bmatrix}
-705\\
231\\
88\\
\end{bmatrix} $$

However, using this vector **x**, $D$**x** $\ne$ **b**.

Does this mean the system is inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean the system is inconsistent?

No.  My response would be why do you think $D \mathbf x = \mathbf b$ would hold for the same $\mathbf x$ that makes $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ true?

There are really two systems here:  $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$ and $D\mathbf x = \mathbf b$.  The consistency of one has nothing to do with the consistency of the other.

A system is consistent if and only if it has at least one solution.  So if you found a solution for the system $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$, then the system is consistent.  And you did find the right solution.  Now turn your attention towards $D \mathbf x = \mathbf b$, keeping it completely separate from $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$.

Comment: Ahh, so the question is really asking if either of them are inconsistent, and to find two separate solutions if they are both consistent. My bad! I thought they were looking for one solution called **x** due to the wording of the question. And the negative sign on 88 is a mistype.

Comment: @Shea, yep, that's right!  I agree, if the question you were given is phrased how you presented it then it's definitely confusing.  I updated my answer to reflect the $-88$ to $88$ typo fix.